# How i can fix ... 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow':.. error

Tags: javascript

Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').

How to fix my problem?
I looked at the answers to this question on the forum but could not solve the problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const api = 'AIzaSyAZaaaXmvFvvvWkZ2bfffbz1oCAqvgSVOGYg'; // Specify your api key here

    // Load API library
    function onLoad() {
        if (api) {
            gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', loadYouTubeApi);
        } else {
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'API key has not been specified!';
        }
    }

    // Set API Key
    function loadYouTubeApi() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey(api);
        search('sitepoint');
    }

    // Call the search.list()
    function search(queryTerm) {
        let request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            part: 'id',
            q: queryTerm
        });
        // Execute the request call and output it in HTML view
        request.execute((response) => {
            const responseString = JSON.stringify(response, '', 2);
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += responseString;
        })
    }
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onLoad" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Run a local web server.

Comment: I have the same problem here. When the page loads for the first time it doesn't work. If the same page is reloaded then it will work.
What is strange is that this even occurs when using 2 different devices. So it doesn't work on the first device, but it works after that on the second device.